# How to replace method reference(::) in java to normal constructor call?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-android

Earlier I have model class in java which uses `autovalue`. Now, it's converted to Kotlin data class.

Model Class -->

```
public static SampleClass create(
@NonNull final SamplePost post,
@NonNull final List<SampleComment> comments) {
return new AutoValue_SampleClass(post, comments);
}
```

Calling Class -->

```
return Observable.zip(...

                    SampleClass::create);
          }
```

new data class -->

```
data class SampleClass(val post: DiscussionPost,
                       val comments: List<SampleComment>) : Parcelable
```

Now how to call it for data class?

Comment: what kind of problem you faced?can you explain?

Comment: how to use it in new scenario? Like how to replace this -> SampleClass::create

Comment: what new scenario ..which class to be used?

Comment: can you add code for `SampleClass.create()`

Answer (score 5):

U can use `SampleClass::new` to call the constructor.

Comment: Ah yes, if the call to `zip` is still in Java and not translated to Kotlin as well, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Is there is something wrong with my question as someone dislike it. I am new here so If you can help me understanding it if the question is wrong or wrongly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a constructor call, but a constructor reference. The syntax for it [is `::SampleClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#constructor-references). But this may not trigger SAM conversion, in which case you'll need

```
 Observable.zip(...,
                { post, comments -> SampleClass(post, comments) })
```

EDIT: The above assumes that `zip` is called from Kotlin, if you want to call it from Java, see @ebasha's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)